# Is it poor practice to set state within JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, setstate

I'm working on showing a series of images with next and previous arrows. I don't want the next and previous arrows to show until the image loads.  I have a state variable to track when the image loads. Is it okay to set this variable from within JSX or better to call a function that sets the state variable?

I don't want to trigger a series of re renders, but I feel like this won't happen because it should only setState once the image loads.  Also, I'd like to adhere to best practices.

Please let me know what you think is best, Thank you!

```
  const handleImageLoad = () => { // Track when image is loaded to show next/prev arrows once image is loaded
    setIsImageLoaded(true);
  };


return (
  { post.images && post.images.length > 0 && (
    <div className="postImages">
      {isImageLoaded && post.images.length > 1 && currentImageIndex != 0 &&(
        <img
        onClick={prevImage}
        className="postImagesNav"
        src="/images/chevron-left.svg"
        alt="Previous"
        />
      )}

      {/* Solution One
      <img 
        id="currentPostImage" 
        src={post.images[currentImageIndex]} 
        onLoad={() => handleImageLoad()} 
        alt={`Image ${currentImageIndex}`} 
      />
      */}
      
      {/* Solution Two */}
      <img 
        id="currentPostImage"
        src={post.images[currentImageIndex]}
        onLoad={() => setIsImageLoaded(true)}
        alt={`Image ${currentImageIndex}`}
      />

      {isImageLoaded && post.images.length > 1 &&  currentImageIndex < post.images.length - 1 &&(
        <img
          onClick={nextImage}
          className="postImagesNav"
          src="/images/chevron-right.svg"
          alt="Next"
          />
      )}
    </div>
  )}
);
```

Comment: Doesn't make much difference. Do whichever you find easier to read. Personally i would do #2.

Comment: in solution one you can just write `onLoad={handleImageLoad}`